# Proper CSS to style nested element

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a CSS dropdown. I would like to be able to add a class `active` to list elements in my dropdown to show the particular item is the current selection. The problem is, I cannot get the text colour to change. The background does, but not the text...

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tMND4/4/

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nice test items</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
               <li><a href="#">Sonic Screwdriver</a></li>
               <li class="active"><a href="#">TARDIS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Long Scarf</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    padding:10px;
}

.dropdown > li{
    width:200px; /*or anything you want!*/
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:2px; /*all things wont stick to the side */
}

.dropdown li a{
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px; /*line it up with sublinks */
}

.dropdown li .submenu{
    display:none; /*hide submenu*/
}
/* child selector to prevent style propagation*/
.dropdown > li:hover{
    border:1px solid #666;
}

/* child selector to prevent style propagation*/
.dropdown > li:hover a {
    padding: 4px; /*reduced padding to compensate for border*/
}

.dropdown li:hover .submenu{
    display:block; /*display submenu*/
}

.dropdown li:hover .submenu a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px; /*line it up with links */
}

.dropdown li:hover .submenu a:hover{
    background: #DDD;
}

.active{ 
    background:#666;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to specificity. You have to be more specific with your `.active` selector.

For example:

```
.dropdown li.active a { 
    background:#666;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tMND4/5/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
.dropdown li a{
    color:#666;
}
```

trumps this:

```
.active {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Because you are applying `active` to the wrapping LI rather than the A.

This may fix it:

```
.dropdown li.active a {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: again, `!important` is usually the wrong answer. I'm not sure why the above doesn't work without spending more time on it. This is why having some many different levels of specificity in your CSS becomes a headache.